# Other way to request SFMC Access token

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, marketingcloudapi

Is there another way of getting access token from SFMC without using the sample payload/format below:

```
{
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"account_id":"xxxxxxx"
}
```

For the request, we have these requirements:

1. client_id and client_secret will not be included in the body/payload.
2. Value in Authorization Header is: Basic [Base64 encoded ClientID:ClientSecret]
3. Request body will only contain "grant_type=client_credentials".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the only way with a [Server-to-Server integration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/integration-s2s-client-credentials.htm) is to provide the info in the json format they provided.

You do have the option of using a 'web' or 'public app' option to help keep your client_id and secret more secure from the requester, but it requires a bit more of a '[**hullabaloo**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/integration-app-auth-code.htm)' to accomplish, which may not be feasable for some.

You would need to use the **[authorization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/authorization-code.htm)** endpoint for the web or public app - which will still require the client_id, but the client secret will be hidden. The issue is that it requires a bunch more information and set-up for use.

Long story short, without building your own custom solution for users to submit to and then using the SFMC API to gather it there, what you have described is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, @Gortonington for the details!